# What should I use instread of g_strncasecmp?

Tags: c, glib

It looks like g_strncasecmp is deprecated, so I am looking for another function to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs at
http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strncasecmp

"There are therefore two replacement functions: g_ascii_strncasecmp(), which only works on ASCII and is not locale-sensitive, and g_utf8_casefold(), which is good for case-insensitive sorting of UTF-8."

Answer (score 0):

`g_ascii_strncasecmp` for pure ASCII and `g_utf8_casefold` if you have UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be comparing a lot of the same strings, you can gain some speed by creating collation keys. Do this using `g_utf8_collate_key()`, you can then compare the keys case-insensitively using `g_ascii_strcmp()` since the collation key is an ASCII string.